# What does !! mean in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have this code:

```
- (BOOL)isConnected {
    return !!_sessionKey;
}
```

where _sessionKey is defined earlier as:

```
NSString* _sessionKey;
```

the code comes from the facebook-connect for iphone.

Since I am learning Objective-C by looking at code written by other people. The `!!` used in the `isConnection` function seems useless to me, or am I missing something? What does it do?

Comment: Negating the boolean value of the expression twice. Bad coding style for legibility. Not very explicit. C programmers do stuff like this a lot.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `!!` converts the result to either `YES` or `NO`.

Using `!!x` is an idiom from C.  The result of this expression is:

- `!!x == 0` when `x == 0 // x is zero`
- `!!x == 1` when `x != 0 // x is non-zero`

At least in C, you can use any non-zero expression as a value which satisfies the condition of an `if ()` or other conditional control flow.  However, sometimes it is nice to know that the "true value" is represented by `1` rather than merely "non-zero".

In Objective-C, `YES` is defined as `1` rather than as "non-zero".  Thus, in Objective-C, this C idiom becomes more useful.

Another way of putting it:

- `!!x == NO` when `x == NO`
- `!!x == YES` when `x != NO`

Comment: In this case, since _sessionKey appears to be an object, 0 is equivalent to 'nil'.  And, since it's Objective-C, the result is YES or NO, rather than 0 or 1.  

Sorry if I'm just pickin' the fly dung out of the pepper here.

Comment: Absolutely, I did add that.  Benjamin, notice it's a community wiki.  Feel free to add to it.

Comment: What nobody seems to have explicitly pointed out so far: `!!` is not, itself, an operator.  It's just the `!` operator applied twice.

Answer (score 14):

It means "not not".

In this case, the first ! could be interpreted as "doesn't exist", so it means if (not doesn't exist sessionKey).

It's basically a short way to say

```
return (_sessionKey != nil).
```